# How do I handle a RTSP Stream crash and latency delay?

Tags: python, opencv, real-time, rtsp, lag

I am trying to view a RTSP stream from a cctv camera using opencv and then I am trying to feed each of it's frame to a ML model to analyze the video. The problem is either the stream lags (becomes 20-40secs slower than the realtime video), or the script just crashes due to receiving empty frames.  I am using a laptop with ryzen 7 5800H, 3050ti, 32GB ram. When I open the rtsp stream with VLC player it never crashes or skips a frame, but when I do it using my python script either there is frame lag, jitter, slow downs or complete crash due to tcp ack packets not being sent.
**
How can I display the rtsp streams real time while applying my ml model to analyze each of the frames and draw on it ?
**

Below is the gist of my code.

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Doing image processing here e.g.
    processed_frame = some_processing_function(frame)

    # Display the frame 
 
    cv2.putText(processed_frame, text_gen, (x1, y1-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, color, 1)
    cv2.imshow('Processed Stream', processed_frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I have tried out multi-threading, ffmpeg, using a buffer to store incoming frames, tried h.264/h.265, reducing resolution.

The results were stream delay and python script crash

Comment: Is this is the function some_processing_function(frame)? If yes, then cv2.putText(frame,...,)

Comment: @toyotaSupra I did this but still getting lags/ delays and rtsp stream crash

Comment: It takes a bit of time to process a frame and already by that time the next frame comes hence the acknowlegement packet for the incoming frame is not sent and therefore the stream crashes i guess

Comment: One last question. Did you upgraded ffmpeg?

Comment: Have you measured how long `some_processing_function`?  If it takes (for example) 2 frame times, then you CANNOT process every frame.  It's impossible.  You'll have to decimate to every 3rd frame.

Comment: no i did not upgrade ffmpeg

Comment: @TimRoberts I'll try doing this and see if it works or not

Comment: @TimRoberts i have an update. The stream is now playing almost close to realtime but it does have some jitters and does not look as smooth as the realtime rtsp video feed. What I did was I integrated threading and multiprocessing along with your idea. I skipped 5 frames instead of processing all of the frames. 

Now, I need to figure out how to make the stream quality less jittery and more smooth